# iptables u32 can match 4 bytes maximum?

Tags: iptables

I would like to match RDP packet with mstshash cookie with u32 iptable's ext. on Debian Jessie with

`Linux version 3.16.0-4-amd64 (debian-kernel@lists.debian.org) (gcc version 4.8.4 (Debian 4.8.4-1) ) #1 SMP Debian 3.16.39-1+deb8u2 (2017-03-07)`

Next rule works (TPKT v3, length 47):

```
-m u32 --u32 "0>>22 & 0x3C @ 12>>26 & 0x3C @ 0=0x0300002f"
```

But if next 4 byte check added for COTP PDU "CR connect request":

```
-m u32 --u32 "0>>22 & 0x3C @ 12>>26 & 0x3C @ 0=0x0300002f && 0=0x2ae0000"
```

rule doesn't match anymore. But I need to check more byte sequences in packet.

Part of packet I'm inspect:

```
0x0030:  ffff fab3 0000 0300 002f 2ae0 0000 0000  ........./*.....
0x0040:  0043 6f6f 6b69 653a 206d 7374 7368 6173  .Cookie:.mstshas
```

Does it mean u32 can check 4 bytes only and not byte sequences in different locations?

Comment: u32 can only match 4 bytes, yes. There is also u16 and u8 for matching 2 bytes and a single byte, respectively. But you can invoke multiple "u" rules together, of varying lengths, to match multiple byte patterns at multiple offsets within the packet payload.

Comment: iptables v1.4.21: u32: option "--u32" can only be used once.

Comment: I have just tested this on a CentOS 6 box. I can pass multiple "--u32" arguments after the "-m u32" argument. Make sure you passing multiple "--u32", "--u16" or "--u8" arguments *after* the single "-m u32" argument, which invokes the "u32" iptables module (the name may be confusing, as this single module supports all three u32, u16 and u8 matching "modes").

Comment: now i'm trying  in one rule  `-m u32 --u32 "0>>22 & 0x3C @ 12>>26 & 0x3C @ 0=0x0300002f" -m u32 --u32 "0>>22 & 0x3C @ 12>>26 & 0x3C @ 4@ 0=0x2ae00000"` and rule accepted but don't match

Comment: Try: `-m u32 --u32 "0>>22 & 0x3C @ 12>>26 & 0x3C @ 0=0x0300002f" --u32 "0>>22 & 0x3C @ 12>>26 & 0x3C @ 4@ 0=0x2ae00000"`

Comment: In my case `-m u32 --u32 "0>>22 & 0x3C @ 12>>26 & 0x3C @ 0=0x0300002f" 
    --u32 "0>>22 & 0x3C @ 12>>26 & 0x3C @ 4@ 0=0x2ae00000"` iptables v1.4.21: u32: option "--u32" can only be used once. Sorry

Comment: Unfortunately, I have no further suggestions. Please update your initial question with the OS version you are using and maybe someone else will be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

When you need to match more than what a single iptables rule will allow, you can use multiple rules. The first rule contains the first match and jumps to a chain with the second rule in it, then the second rule contains the other match and the actual target action.